# What webserver should I use to host RoR apps in Windows?

Tags: windows, web-server, ruby-on-rails

I need to setup a dedicated server to host [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) (an open source Ruby-on-Rails bug tracker).

What is the best web server to accomplish this?

1. Apache
2. [Mongrel](http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/)
3. IIS
4. something else?

It must run on Windows (flavor is optional but 2008-x64 preferred).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongrel is no longer active/supported. I couldn't get it to work on WS2008 with Ruby 1.9.3.  Alternatives are puma and Thin.
see also: http://www.redmine.org/boards/1/topics/31297

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any of them should be fine as long as you don't expect to encounter any sort of serious load.  Go with whatever you're most comfortable with.

In this particular case I'd probably go with IIS simply because its built in, integrated with Windows well, and works well.

Its been a while since I played with this but I believe this was the link I used as a starting point:

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/02/18/10-steps-to-get-Ruby-on-Rails-running-on-Windows-with-IIS-FastCGI.aspx

This link looks a little newer...

http://ruslany.net/2008/08/ruby-on-rails-in-iis-70-with-url-rewriter/

Comment: Do you have any personal experience with IIS? I've read that *if* you get it working, it can be flakey. If that's not true, I'm with you.

Comment: Yes and Yes... its NOT very straightforward.  Its been a while since I played with it but it has got easier.  Take a look at this link as a starting point:  http://ruslany.net/2008/08/ruby-on-rails-in-iis-70-with-url-rewriter

Comment: IIS/FastCGI with Rails is nontrivial to setup. I've spent hours and got nowhere. Apache/Mongrel is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using IIS or apache as a proxy to a mongrel cluster since you said you need it to be Windows. If you had Hyper-V, I would totally suggest that you use a linux VM.